# How to send request to external server in Swift for stats purposes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am building my first  iOS game. Now I would like to know how many people have played the game, and how many games in total have been played. As far as I know Apple does not show these kind of stats, so I figured the best way to do this is to ping a hidden URL to my webserver every time a users plays a round of the game.

The game I am making is written in Swift. I have tried to find some sample code to ping external URL's, but so far I have not found anything.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why not send a HTTP request and send an integer to a php or python script? Or do you specifically just want it to increment database values? Also you'll need to be careful so that Apple doesn't reject your app due to the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best thing to do is to use google analytics.
It will give you a lot of statistics (like how many times each screen has been seen etc)
https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/mobile?hl=fr

But if you want to do it on your own you can easily call an URL on your web service. Personally I love AlamoFire (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)
there is a lot of sample on their github page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure an external API to connect your swift app with a db running on a server.

In swift, to make pretty request to external services, you can use [alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). It's a pretty library of the same creator of [afnetworking](https://github.com/afnetworking/afnetworking). In a simple way, you can make http networking in Swift. Alamofire only runs for IOS 8 or later.

You need to install alamofire, call the library in your viewcontroler (import Alamofire) and make your request. Read the library documentation, it's clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply trying to hit a url on your website, without passing any data, you can do it very simply by.

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://mywebserver.com/secret_end_point")
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!)
    task.resume()
```

Comment: This is the most basic async url request, you can do a lot of configuring if you want to change the behavior in app, and you'd likely want to account for the fact that the user may not have network connectivity etc...